# using "determinant" for predictive model

Tags: data-analysis, prediction, causality

I have created a logistic regression model to predict an outcome. I'm wondering if it's appropriate in my analysis and writing to use "determinant"? I use "factor" "independent variables" etc. but I'm curious about if this particular word and its connotations.

Answer (score 0):

## Use "Predictor" and "Outcome"

The word "determinant" already has a different mathematical meaning and might thus be confusing.  The distinction between "independent" vs. "dependent" is sometimes used, but it can be confusing and is not correct strictly speaking (independent of what?). The word "factor" is used colloquially, but may be mistaken with factors of a product in a mathematical context.

In the context of a prediction model, it is typical to distinguish between *predictor* variables and *outcome* variables, and I would recommend sticking to this convention.